# Android phone unresponsive touch

Tags: touchscreen, vivo

I have had my Vivo Y20i for 2 years now. But this past 6 months, I've been experiencing some touch issues where part of my screen doesn't respond to my touches, and to make it work again is to lock my phone and then unlock it and everything works as normal. Sometimes it takes 2 to 3 unlocks before it returns to normal. It's pretty irritating especially when I'm playing something or typing something, doesn't respond to my touches, and sometimes ghost touches. The time it occurs is random.

I do not have any applications that can alter any touches or systems whatsoever. I only have the default apps (YouTube, Google, Etc.) and Mobile Legends. And I haven't dropped my phone since then.

Comment: When you lock the phone, the screen goes off, correct? And when you unlock it the screen goes on again. I would assume that this is similar to a reboot of the screen and touch system. You can try to perform a factory reset to check if the software has an impact, but to me this sounds like a hardware problem which will stay and may be get worse over time until touch completely fails.

Comment: Yeah i have tried factory reset several times but it didn't solve the problem. As you've said maybe its on the hardware.